# Particular solution of third order PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> $$\partial_t u + \partial^{3}_x u = 0$$
>   show that this PDE has a particular solution in the form of a plane wave,
>   $$u_k(x,t) = \exp(-i\,w\,t - i\,k\,x)$$ if the frequency $w$ obeys the appropriate dispersion relation, $w = w(k)$.

In the past I have solved up to 2nd order PDE's using separation of variables, Sturm-Liouville method. But since the all coefficients in the PDE has different powers I am confused how to solve this problem. Seems like I can not solve this problem using the methods I used to solve 2nd order PDE's. Any help?

Comment: What happens when you plug this into the PDE.  Can you show that it works, provided there is a certain relation (which you must find) between $w$ and $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a linear PDE you can use the principle of superposition to form solutions with 
$$
u \sim \exp(−iwt−ikx)
$$
then inserting the plane wave solution you obtain
$$
-i\omega u + (-ik)^3u = \left(-i\omega-i^3k^3\right)u = -i(\omega -k^3)u = 0
$$
or the dispersion relation is
$$
w(k) = k^3
$$
if this relation is true then you can use the plane wave above.

If you want to solve you are missing quite a few pieces of information such as initial conditions etc..

Comment: I get $w=k^3$. Here $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: @AleksasDomarkas I agree. I am not sure why I did it that way - I must have had a mini brain lapse. Thanks!